# Symmetric dominance regions surrounding a Gaussian prime

Tags: complex-geometry, discrete-geometry, prime-numbers

Let $z=a + b i$ be a complex number which is a [Gaussian prime](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaussianPrime.html),
on neither the $x$- nor the $y$-axis.
So $a^2+b^2$ is a prime.
Construct a region $D(z)$ surrounding $z$ which is the
largest [orthogonally convex polygon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_convex_hull) surrounding $z$ that is empty of
Gaussian primes. ($D$ for *Dominance*.)
More precisely, define $D(z)$ as the union
of rectangles $R$ that (a) strictly include $z$,
but (b) are empty of other Gaussian primes in the interior of $R$.
Two examples are shown below: $z=1+i$, and $z=4+5i$, where the marked points on the
boundary of $D(z)$ are Gaussian primes:

     
[image]

It seems likely that $D(z)$ is not well-defined, based on a comment
of François Brunault to 
an earlier MO question, "[Gaussian prime spirals](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/91423/gaussian-prime-spirals)":

> it's unknown whether there are infinitely many Gaussian primes of the form $n+i$ with $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Nevertheless, I wonder if this question might avoid running into an unsolved problem:

> **Q**.  Is there a $z=a + b i$, with $a \neq 0$ and $b \neq 0$, such that
>   $D(z)$ is symmetric about both a vertical line through $z$ and a horizontal line through $z$?

In the examples above, although $D(1+i)$ is a square, it is not symmetric about $1+i$.
And $D(4+5 i)$ is symmetric about a horizontal through $z$ but not a vertical.

My guess is that the answer to **Q** is *Yes*, but I just haven't found the $z$ that
leads to symmetry. My question can be answered by a single example.
I am seeking some (minimal) structure to the distribution of the Gaussian primes.
Thanks for thoughts/ideas!